# How to fetch rows and separate values with comma in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get a list of all emails in database and concatenate all emails in a php variable separated with a comma. This is what im using:

```
 $emailres=do_sqlquery("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `id` > 1",true);
 $qtdemails=mysql_num_rows($emailres);
 while($emailrows = mysql_fetch_row($emailres)) {
    for($i=0; $i < $qtdemails; $i++){
        $allemails .= $emailrows[$i].",";
    }
 }
```

If I have 5 emails in database, this is what im getting in the $allemails variable:

```
1@email.com,,,,,2@email.com,,,,,3@email.com,,,,,4@email.com,,,,,5@email.com,,,,,
```

This is what i need

```
1@email.com,2@email.com,3@email.com,4@email.com,5@email.com
```

Would you help me?
Thank you

OBS: I know its deprecated and i really don't care, but if you want help me to do it the right way i would love to learn, otherwise just help me fix my code and its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, add all those emails to a new empty array (remove your string concatenation code).

```
$allemails[] = $emailrows[$i];
```

Then outside your loop simply do

```
$string=implode("," , $allEmails);
```

Although you mentioned you don't want to be told about deprecated code but you are using even deprecated code incorrectly :P Your for loop is not required at all. You could simply do a `fetch_assoc` and extract those emails using only that `while` loop

**Edit**: Since you asked

```
        while($emailrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailres)) {
            if(!empty($emailrows['email']))
              $allEmails[]=$emailrows['email'];
        }
```

**Edit 2**

As @sgt mentioned in comments below, Your query returns empty email addresses; Why so? Although I have added a check to not include those in the output but then you should update your query to not return such record in the first place.

```
SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `id` > 1 AND email <>''
```

Comment: Since my code is incorrect, can you pls post a full correct code? im very noob to this... thank you Hanky 웃 Panky

Comment: `implode()` will also include the empty values to the string i think.before storing in array there should be a check for empty emails.

Comment: There are no empty values there, and if their query returns empty email values then query should be updated first.

Comment: this is the point.either add the check or update the query. :)

Comment: Nope that check is not needed. An email address is usually never allowed to be Null in a users table. And we have no indication that OP allows that to be null. Hence neither the query needs to be updated nor any check needs to be added :)

Comment: know that but the above mentioned query is returning empty emails. :)

Comment: Oh I see, yes you are right. Well spotted. I just checked their existing output. You were right :)

Comment: Guys this is not returning empty emails, my code was wrong, it was inserting extra commas between the addresses. The answer solved the problem. thank you all. Curiously the number of commas was equal to the number of rows!

Comment: Oh Yes that was your loop doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailary = array();
while($emailrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailres)) {
        $emailary[] = $emailrows['email'];
     }

$email_string = implode(",",$emailary);
echo $email_string;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while($emailrows = mysql_fetch_row($emailres)) {
 if(!empty($emailrows['email'])){
     $email_list.= $emailrows['email'].",";
 }
}

$email_list = rtrim($email_list,',');
```

There is a function rtrim which remove the last , from the variable.

Comment: Same story as mentioned above